# Define defaultSnippets for JSONSchema additionalProperties

Tags: visual-studio-code

As the title suggests, I would like to define a vscode `defaultSnippet` for the `additionalProperites` of a JSONObject. The JSONSchema looks like the following

```
"$schema ": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"type":"object",
"additionalProperties":{
   "type": "object",
   "properties":{
      "name":{"type":"string"}
   }
}
```

So just adding `defaultSnippet` property does not seem to work:

```
"$schema ": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"type":"object",
"additionalProperties":{
   "defaultSnippets": [{
         "label": "test",
         "description": "Additional property template",
         "body": {
         "$1": {
             "name": "$2"
             }
         }
   }],
   "type": "object",
   "properties":{
      "name":{"type":"string"}
   }
}
```

Is there a workaround to obtain the same behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but vscode at this moment is only checking `properties` for snippets. I had the same problem, so I've created Pull Request with fix for this issue.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-json-languageservice/pull/62

You can replace default extension if you in rush or just wait for merge and update.